# How can I give an href to the link I took from my json data file?

Tags: json, database, vue.js

I have a data file of Json type and I can easily pull and print the data here. But for some reason, I can't print the link from the `href="{{data.winnerlink}}` or `href="etherscan.io/tx/{{data.winner}}"`, even though I tried the following.

Answer (score 1):

The `{{ }}` syntax can't be used inside of dynamic attributes. Also, you need to prefix with `v-bind:` or short `:`.

Try this: `:href="data.winnerlink"`

[Vue.js Documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind)

Comment: It worked, I guess I couldn't see it because of focusing. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: @ReşatAkkuş  Glad to help! Could you mark your question as answered then? Thanks!